# My WriteToFile function is not saving anything despite not coming up with any errors?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to this platform so excuse any mistakes in this question. I am trying to write a program that allows a teacher to input 30 students names and their marks to 3 tests each out of 20, 25 and 35, respectfully. I need it to save the inputted details afterwards, this is where I am having problems. it is not saving the details.

Below is my 'WriteToFile' function:

```
def WriteFile(Names, MarkTest1, MarkTest2, MarkTest3):
    FileName = raw_input('Please Enter The File Name: ')
    print

    WriteFile = open(FileName, 'w')
    Lines = ''

    for Pupil in range(len(Names)):
        Lines = Lines + str(Names[Pupil]) + ', ' + str(MarkTest1[Pupil]) + ', ' + str(MarkTest2[Pupil]) + ', ' + str(MarkTest3[Pupil]) + '\n'

    WriteFile.write(Lines)
    WriteFile.close()
```

Below is part of the program that inputs and saves the details:

```
if Choice in 'Ww':
    for P in range(Pupils):
        Name = getName("Please Enter The Students Name: ")
        print
        Mark1 = getMark("Please Enter The Students Mark For Test 1: ", 20)
        print
        Mark2 = getMark("Please Enter The Students Mark For Test 2: ", 25)
        print
        Mark3 = getMark("Please Enter The Students Mark For Test 3: ", 35)
        print

        Names.append(Name)
        MarkTest1.append(Mark1)
        MarkTest2.append(Mark2)
        MarkTest3.append(Mark3)

    WriteFile(Names, MarkTest1, MarkTest2, MarkTest3)

    getContinueChoice()
```

Hope someone can help, Thanks.

Comment: Please fix your indentation. Currently it is very hard to understand what belongs to the function.

Comment: Also , it would be easier to help you if you include the traceback

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  
We should be able to paste your given code into a text file and reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the traceback. Now, please format it as code, so that we see the exact line breaks which Python showed you.  Right now, the traceback is all mashed together, and hard to decipher. I second @Prune's recommendation to read up on making a "Minimal, complete, verifiable example".

Comment: Your function `WriteFile()` is almost certainly indented wrong here.  The line beginning `Filename =` should be indented with respect to the line beginning `def WriteFile`, just above it.

Comment: Hi guys sorry for the change in question, but I have fixed all ident errors for you and it should be able to be read easily.

Comment: Yes.  However, your code still doesn't run independently.  **Choice** is not defined, and we have to hand-type input.  You should have a driver program that forces some representative values so that we can reproduce the error simply by running the file.

Answer (score 0):

`IndexError: string index out of range` occurs when you try to access a character of string beyond its length among many other reasons.

ex.

```
a = 'Hello, World!'
print a[0]
print a[42] # This will cause IndexError
b='24'
print b[1] # prints 2
print b[2] # IndexError
```

In your case, You are trying to access `MarkTest1[Pupil]`.

I see `MarkTest1` is `Mark1` from the calling function. Which is basically user input.

I am assuming length of `Names` is greater than this string input. Lets say length of `Names` is 3. Mark1 is `'24'` (see this is a string).
In the loop

```
for Pupil in range(len(Names)):
    ...
```

Pupil assumes `[0,1,2]`
And, when you access `MarkTest1[2]` which is basically `'24'[2]` or `b[2]` in my example.

So, you are getting IndexError.

Now What do you do:

From here you need to debug. See what exactly is each variable before the the error occurs by printing them. Gives you an insight. And, lot of learning.

Have fun debugging :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, but I am now experiencing another problem, please have a look at my new question.

Comment: Okay. For future. Pls keep question unchanged and raise new questions.

Comment: I would suggest you to check if you are able to write a file with some random text. And, then try to write the string you created.

Comment: Ok, I will have a go. Sorry as I say I am new here.